# Pin several images at touch points - Android

Tags: android

Am trying to place pins wherever the user touches on an imageView. Assume a map (like Google Maps) & the user touches a point, say point A, and a pin is drawn at that point. Then, the user touches point B, then another pin (not the same previous pin relocated!) needs to be drawn at point B and so on. Right now, am able to draw a pin at the point where the user touches on the screen like this :

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
....
    Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon_locationmarker);
    canvas.drawBitmap(marker, mLastTouchX, mLastTouchY, null);
.... 
    canvas.restore();
}
```

However, I don't want to relocate one pin across the screen wherever the user touches (which is what the above code is doing). I want to put several pins at all points wherever user touches. Am new to Android. Please help.

Comment: bro are you completed? can you send sample project same like this ..I am new in android ...Please help me ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eluvatar is right, you needs to create a list to store all your mark. Here's the sample of code. Remember, do add list when only motionEvent is either Action_UP or Action_DOWN only. Otherwise, there will be full of point.

```
public ArrayList<Coordinate> pointsList;

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
....
    Bitmap marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.icon_locationmarker);
    for(Coordinate coor : pointsList){
        canvas.drawBitmap(marker, coor.x, coor.y, null);
    }

.... 
    canvas.restore();
}

public View.OnTouchListener mListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            pointsList.add(new Coordinate(event.getX(), event.getY()));
        }

        return false;
    }
};

class Coordinate{
    float x;
    float y;
    public Coordinate(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

**edit:** change int x,y to float x,y

Comment: I'd recommend using a float all the way though rather than casting to int as drawBitmap as a version that takes a float, other then that good example.

Comment: Thank you @edisonthk ! I guessed we need to maintain the points, but I wasn't sure where to re-draw them. 1. should they necessarily be re-drawn every time? Will that not slow the App if, say, there are 10-12 points re-drawn? 2. The other issue is about scale. The image can be zoomed & panned around. Say, the user marks a pin when in normal image size, then, say, he zooms in and then marks another point. Do i compare the original image size to the current size and calculate the scale & then calculate that, if the user zooms out again, where should I mark that pin? Thoughts?

Comment: 1. Let's say your device core is 1GHz and drawBitmap process in 1KHz (predict), then 1K * 10 pins or 1k * 50 pins. As long as your are not drawing a large images that a single drawBitmap process require almost 1MHz, there should be no problems.
2. About scale, I guess google-maps store the pins in longitude latitude instead of xy position given by onTouch MotionEvent. So, you should think about reference value instead of image size.
3. If you are thinking of zooming, you should use redraw to redraw your pin's position when zooming.

Comment: bro can you give any example like github?

Answer (score 2):

you need to create a list of "touch points". then on touch add a new touch point to the list, then onDraw you iterate through that list and draw a marker on each point.

you'll also need to make sure you save the list of touch points on save instance state otherwise you'll lose them on rotate and on activity pause.

Comment: Thank you @Eluvatar ! I guessed we need to maintain the points, but I wasn't sure where to re-draw them. 1. should they necessarily be re-drawn every time? Will that not slow the App if, say, there are 10-12 points re-drawn? 2. The other issue is about scale. The image can be zoomed & panned around. Say, the user marks a pin when in normal image size, then, say, he zooms in and then marks another point. Do i compare the original image size to the current size and calculate the scale & then calculate that, if the user zooms out again, where should I mark that pin? Thoughts?

Comment: 1, it's no big deal as noted on the other answer unless you have a huge number of points. as for scale it depends on what we're dealing with, google maps does not scale pins when zooming (they stay the same size no matter the zoom level) imagine placing a pin zoomed in all the way on google maps, then you zoom all the way out, if the pin scaled you would not be able to see it that far out. As for panning you will need to figure out how to relate an on screen touched position to your content.